# Make a $_GET into variable or place into URL

Tags: php

How do you place a $_GET['****']; into a string or make it into a variable.
For Example i have this url:

http://localhost/PhpProject2/product_page.php?rest_id=3/area=Enfield.

I want to get the area and rest_id from the url. in order to redirect another page to this exact page.

```
echo"<script>window.open('product_page.php?rest_id= 'put get here'/area='put get here'','_self')</script>";
```

I have so far done this:

```
if(isset($_GET['rest_id'])){
if(isset($_GET['rest_city'])){

 $_GET['rest_id'] = $rest_id;
 }
 }
```

This obviously does not work, so my question is how do i make the 2 $_GET into a variable or call the $_GET into the re-direct string.

**What i have tired so far**

```
echo"<script>window.open('product_page.php?rest_id=' . $GET['rest_id'] . '/area='put get here'','_self')</script>";
```

How or what is the best practice?

Comment: You are using the wrong separator for your query string. It should be `http://localhost/PhpProject2/product_page.php?rest_id=3&area=Enfield`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, first things first. in your URL you have to separate the parameters using an ampersand "&",  like this

```
http://localhost/PhpProject2/product_page.php?rest_id=3&area=Enfield
```

Also, you have to assign the $_GET value to a variable, not the other way around, like this

```
$rest_id = $_GET['rest_id'];
```

so if you create a PHP file named `product_page.php`  and use the url i gave you, and your PHP code looks like this, it should work..

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['rest_id'])){
    $rest_id = $_GET['rest_id'];
}

if (isset($_GET['rest_id'])){
    $area = $_GET['area'];
}

$url = 'other_page.php?rest_id=' . $rest_id . '&area=' . $area;
header("Location: $url");
?>
```

The question here is why do you want to redirect from this page to the other, and not send the parameters directly to the "other_page.php"????

Comment: I have a mini cart. So on adding the item to the cart, the user is sent to shopping_cart.php? add_item='item_number'. So on the shopping_cart page after a item has been added i need to redirect back to the right product page

Comment: oohh.. ok... well.. if this is the solution for you don't forget to mark it as the right answer! xD